# I have a question on infinite products

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence, infinite-product

The question: Suppose $F(z) = \prod_{j = 1}^{\infty} [1 + f_{j}(z)]$ converges uniformily on compact subsets  of a open set $U \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ to a limit that could be zero or non-zero. Suppose that $F(c) = 0$ for some $c \in U$. Prove or disprove: there is a $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $1 + f_{j}(c) = 0$.

Here's my work: I do think this is false but I am having trouble coming up with a normally convergent sequence of functions. Let $U = D(0, 1/2)-\{ {0} \}$ and $f_{j}(z) = \frac{z}{j^2}$. I want to try to examine $F(-1/2)$. Is this a good example? Thank you very much!

Comment: Convergence of a numerical product is always taken to a non-zero value (0 is considered divergent) so for functions, getting zero means a term is zero, so the answer is yes

Comment: Sometimes with infinite series and products of sequences of functions, it can help to start with a sequence of constant functions so that your experience with infinite series and products of numbers can aid you.  Also, sometimes, taking a logarithm of a product to turn it into a series can also aid your intuition.

Comment: I edited the question. I am supposing that the limit of the infinite product could converge to a limit that equals to 0 or some other nonzero limit